# Trying to install NNTP reader tin and parsdate.y error

Tags: centos, nntp

I am trying to install tin on a CentOS 7 VM.  ./configure runs fine, and then when I run make build, I get...

```
[user@db3 tin-2.4.5]$ make build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/tin-2.4.5/src'
expect 6 shift/reduce conflicts ...
./parsdate.y
./parsdate.y: line 1: fg: no job control
./parsdate.y: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
./parsdate.y: line 3: active.c: command not found
./parsdate.y: line 4: active.c: command not found
./parsdate.y: line 5: active.c: command not found
./parsdate.y: line 6: active.c: command not found
./parsdate.y: line 7: active.c: command not found
./parsdate.y: line 8: active.c: command not found
./parsdate.y: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./parsdate.y: line 9: ` *              Originally written by Steven M. Bellovin <smb@research.att.com>'
make[1]: *** [parsdate.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/tin-2.4.5/src'
make: [build] Error 2 (ignored)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem, and in the same environment.

From what I can tell, at this point you may just need to:

```
./configure
make clean
make build
```

Rerunning ./configure after installing bison and chmod 777'ing parsdate.y is how I fixed the compilation errors but it seems you already did the bison part and chmod part.